# C# Mvc Generic Route using Slug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, slug

I'm trying to create a generic route to work with slugs, but I always got an error

The idea is, instead of **www.site.com/controller/action** I get in the url a friendly **www.site.com/{slug}**

e.g. **www.site.com/Home/Open** would be instead **www.site.com/open-your-company**

**Error**

> server error in '/' application  The Resource cannot be found

In my **Global.asax** I have

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //routes.Clear();
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute("DefaultSlug", "{slug}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Open", slug = "" });
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            area = "",
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            slug = ""
        }
    );
}
```

In one of my `cshtml` I have the following link (even when it's commented, there is still the same error).

```
@Html.ActionLink("Open your company", "DefaultSlug", new { controller = "Home", action = "Open", slug = "open-your-company" })
```

EDIT: HomeController

```
public ActionResult Open() { 
    return View(new HomeModel()); 
}
```

Comment: Show the action that `DefaultSlug` Route maps to.

Comment: The action is the Open inside Home `public ActionResult Open()
        {
            return View(new HomeModel());
        }`

Comment: But I guess you got a point, I saw that INSIDE the HomeModel there is some parameters that are accessing the url by position. Will test it now

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31607273/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi How should be the Html.ActionLink ?

Comment: You had the action link correct. It just wasn't mapping to the right route because of how it was configured.

Comment: Here is another way for the action link `@Html.ActionLink("Open your company", "Open", "Home", new { slug = "open-your-company" })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Global.asax you `slug` can not be empty,if empty ,the url will be not go to the default route

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //routes.Clear();
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DefaultSlug",
        url: "{slug}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Open" },
        constraints: new{ slug=".+"});

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            area = "",
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
}
```

And update the HomeController

```
public ActionResult Open(string slug) {
    HomeModel model = contentRepository.GetBySlug(slug);

    return View(model); 
}
```

Testing Route link...

```
@Html.RouteLink("Open your company", routeName: "DefaultSlug", routeValues: new { controller = "Home", action = "Open", slug = "open-your-company" })
```

and Action link...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Open your company", "Open", routeValues: new { controller = "Home", action = "Open", slug = "open-your-company" })
```

both produces...

```
http://localhost:35979/open-your-company
```

Comment: Still testing, but this code will not create "controller/action?slug" ? I'm trying to get something like ***www.site.com/slug*** instead of "www.site.com/controller/action"

Comment: Then use the original action link format you had in your post where you call the route by name `DefaultSlug`

Comment: This is what I'm trying, but didn't seem to work, the error persists. Any idea?

Comment: i believe that the error is because I'm using ActionLink instead I should be using RouteLink ... trying some code to see if work.

Comment: In the html `@Html.RouteLink("Open company", "DefaultSlug", new { slug = "open-your-company", controller = "Home", action = "Open" })` in the asax `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultSlug",
                url: "{slug}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    slug = "",
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Open"
                }
            );` I just didn't figured out how to make it a gereric route, or at LEAST not the need to pass `controller` and `action` in the html too (removing cause the same error)

Comment: @MichelAyres The issue was how the link methods were being called. Once the correct format is used everything worked as expected.

Comment: Now it only gets the first declared route (ignoring even the default)... 
            `routes.MapRoute(name: "OpenSlug", url: "{slug}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Open", slug = "" });` and 
            `routes.MapRoute(name: "TransferSlug", url: "{slug}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Transfer", slug = "" });`

Comment: That's because slug cannot be empty. Check my answer and see how the routes were mapped. Also, in your last comment it looks like the two routes you show have the same template. Is your intention to create a mapping for each action?

Comment: My intent is to create one single route that accepts 'controller' and 'action' as parameters. BUT I could do that, So I was trying to do one route for action (there is only 5 after all) and he is reading as the same route (even the Default is not being read)

Comment: The link `@Html.RouteLink("Open company", "DefaultSlug", new { slug = "open-company" })` works like a charm, perfect. When I try to use it in another link, like `@Html.RouteLink("About us", "DefaultSlug", new { slug = "about-us", controller = "Home", action = "About" })` ... he redirect to the same page *(like a **#**)* the asax is `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultSlug", 
                url: "{slug}", 
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Open" },
                constraints: new{ slug=".+"}
            );`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps I took to accomplish a similar task. This relies on a custom `Slug` field on the model to match against the route.

1. Set up your controller e.g. Controllers\PagesController.cs:

   ```
   public class PagesController : Controller
   {
       // Regular ID-based routing
       [Route("pages/{id}")]
       public ActionResult Detail(int? id)
       {
           if(id == null)
           {
               return new HttpNotFoundResult();
           }

           var model = myContext.Pages.Single(x => x.Id == id);
           if(model == null)
           {
               return new HttpNotFoundResult();
           }
           ViewBag.Title = model.Title;
           return View(model);
       }

       // Slug-based routing - reuse View from above controller.
       public ActionResult DetailSlug (string slug)
       {
           var model = MyDbContext.Pages.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Slug == slug);
           if(model == null)
           {
               return new HttpNotFoundResult();
           }
           ViewBag.Title = model.Title;
           return View("Detail", model);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set up routing in App_Start\RouteConfig.cs

   ```
   public class RouteConfig
   {
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
           // Existing route register code

           // Custom route - top priority
           routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "PageSlug", 
                   url: "{slug}", 
                   defaults: new { controller = "Pages", action = "DetailSlug" },
                   constraints: new {
                       slug = ".+", // Passthru for no slug (goes to home page)
                       slugMatch = new PageSlugMatch() // Custom constraint
                   }
               );
           }

           // Default MVC route setup & other custom routes
       }
   }
   ```
3. Custom IRouteConstraint implementation e.g. Utils\RouteConstraints.cs

   ```
   public class PageSlugMatch : IRouteConstraint
   {
       private readonly MyDbContext MyDbContext = new MyDbContext();

       public bool Match(
           HttpContextBase httpContext,
           Route route,
           string parameterName,
           RouteValueDictionary values,
           RouteDirection routeDirection
       )
       {
           var routeSlug = values.ContainsKey("slug") ? (string)values["slug"] : "";
           bool slugMatch = false;
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(routeSlug))
           {
               slugMatch = MyDbContext.Pages.Where(x => x.Slug == routeSlug).Any();
           }
           return slugMatch;
       }
   }
   ```